# what is mathematical difference between an hermitian operator $\hat A$ and a vector $\vec A$?

Tags: vector-spaces, operator-theory, operator-algebras

what is mathematical difference/relation between an [hermitian operator](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitianOperator.html) $\hat A$ and a vector $\vec A$?

Comment: Your choice of letter A and symbols around it tells me nothing about the operator and the vector in question. So it sounds to me as "what is the difference/relation between a Hermitian operator and a vector?" Well, you can apply operators to vectors - that's about it.

Comment: I'm having a hard time guessing why you think they are similar enough you have to ask this question. Can you include your thoughts leading up to the question?

Answer (score 1):

These are quite different objects. You can apply an operator (Hermitian or not) to a vector to obtain another vector, in fact Hermitian operators are often represented by matrices.